# The algebro-geometric counterpart of the Dijkgraaf-Witten model

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, extended-tqft

Can the Dikgraaf-Witten model for a finite gauge group $G$ [Robbert Dijkgraaf and Edward Witten, Topological Gauge Theories and Group Cohomology, Commun. Math. Phys. 129 (1990), 393] be described in terms of the geometry of moduli spaces $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n,\beta}([*//G])$ of stable maps to the stack $[*//G]$? I strongly suspect the answer is yes, in view of the classical relation between 3-dimensional topological quantum field theories and complex analytic 2-dimensional modular functors, but I'm unaware of rigorous results in this direction.

Comment: I would look at math.QA/0310087 by Alexader Kirillov Jr. Here is the abstract:

In this note, we give a description of the modular functor associated to the Chern-Simons theory with a finite group from the complex-analytic point of view, i.e. as a vector bundle with a flat connection on the moduli space of punctured curves. We show that it can be obtained from the trivial local system on the moduli space of "admissible G-covers" as a direct image under the forgetful map from moduli space of G-covers to the usual moduli space.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this note. Do you know whether the forthcoming papers announced there have then actually been written?

Comment: This paper of Kirillov and Prince suggests yet another forthcominig paper, where such details will be worked out: arXiv:0807.0939.

I'm guessing that Prince was a student of Kirillov's and was given this as a thesis problem. 

Comment: You might be interested in these notes of David Ben-Zvi: http://www.math.utexas.edu/users/benzvi/GRASP/lectures/NWTFT/nwtft.pdf

Comment: cool!.. and since there's no better way to carefully read them than latexing them.. (I'll post a link here as latexing is complete)

Comment: I believe that there are already LaTeX'd notes from Ben-Zvi's lectures somewhere on the internet. Do a google search -- iirc, they're located somewhere in the nCafe and/or nLab.

Comment: I'm apparently unable to find them: on nLab I was only able to find other handwritten notes. I'll try and search better; in the meanwhile, should you happen to find them..

Comment: Here they are:
http://math.ucr.edu/~alex/Ncafe_postings/DBZ_lecture1.pdf
http://math.ucr.edu/~alex/Ncafe_postings/DBZ_lecture2.pdf
http://math.ucr.edu/~alex/Ncafe_postings/DBZ_lecture3.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been done, in a variety of related ways.  A lot of the difficulty is in defining an appropriate notion of a "stable" map to [pt/G].

The earliest mathematical work I know of is Chen & Ruan's "orbifold cohomology", which is done in the symplectic category.  (Caveats:  Abramovich's lecture notes on orbifold GW theory quote a 1996 letter from Kontsevich, who outlines a lot of the basic ideas in 2 pages.  Also, string theorists were looking at **non**-topological sigma models to orbifolds at least as far back as Dixon, Harvey, Vafa, & Witten's 1985 papers.)

In algebraic geometry, this stuff has been studied by Jarvis, Kaufmann, & Kimura, who focused on G-bundles, and by Abramovich, Graber, & Vistoli, who figured out how to deal with D-M stacks.

(You can also carry out these constructions in K-theory for finite-dimensional Lie groups.  See, for example, Frenkel, Teleman, & [cough].)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the references. I'm actually more interested in the tqft aspects than in the rigorous definition of the moduli stack of stable maps to a DM stack. Kirillov's paper math.QA/0310087 very much goes in the direction I'm interested, but it is extremely sketchy.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit the above answer, so AJ, perhaps you can do it for me and change Dixon, Harvey, Vafa, & Strominger to Dixon, Harvey, Vafa, & Witten.  

Comment: In addition to these references, check out "Consistent Orientations of Moduli Spaces" by Freed-Hopkins-Teleman, particularly section 4 of that paper.